# MahApps icons for text editing

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

**Question**: `1`) Which of the [following icon packs](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks) contain text editing icons (copy/paste, numbering lists, etc.) `2`) and, which ones contain symbols such as summation, square roots etc.)? Because of the size concern, I would like to install only the ones I need from [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/wiki/Install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse the icons using their icon pack browser found here https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/releases/download/4.8.0/IconPacks.Browser.Release-v4.8.0-rc0006.zip

Since file size is a concern you can use that browser to copy the path geometry so you don't have to install an entire pack just the icons you want and just reference them in your App.xaml file in a PathGeometry item to use them

[image]

Comment: Using the browser you suggested, I got all the icons I needed. But I was wondering which NuGet package do they belong to. But you made it even simpler for me by suggesting the use of `path geometry` (thank you). I used the `All` tab of the browser and searched for the icons I needed. For instance, I typed `list` to filter the search for the list icons and picked a particular `numbered list` I needed. Same for the other icons I needed. Many thanks - and welcome to `StackOverflow`.

Comment: Your'e very welcome glad I could help, at the top right below the filter list it will tell you which package the selected icon belongs to.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. In your screenshot, I did not pay attention to the second word of (for example) `PackIconBootstrapIcons` that, in fact, tells the package name (which in your case is BootstrapIcons). But your suggestion came out to be even better since I don't have to install the packages at all.

Comment: You're very welcome